# How to expand Android version target version for existing app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

I have an app in the `Play Store` that originally targeted API 19+, this was great, then somehow just before Christmas we uploaded a new version that targeted API 21+. Not so much of a problem as an annoyance, but when I uploaded a new version of the app today I got an error on the API 21+ update and was told that I had to have a version that targeted API 23+.

I want to get this app back so it covers all versions of Android from 4.4 > 8.1. But I don't know how.
I uploaded the API21+ apk, and the API23+ version (with different version numbers in the same release (because you have to do that), but the error still persists for the 21+, so I had to remove it to get the update in.

How can I achieve this, currently stuck with an api 23 app, which should be 19.

I am using `Xamarin.Forms`, in `Visual Studio 2017`, all of the latest updates, publishing through the web as you can't upload from VS if you need multiple packages in the same release (I don't think).

Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**
Right, I have the solution to my problem, but I have no idea how to execute it. How do I set the minSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion, using code, in Xamarin and Visual Studio. As the manifest is written at compile time, my options for editing the base manifest wont work (I tried).

Comment: not sure how xamarin works, but do you see build.gradle? you should be able to adjust the api there

Comment: I can adjust the api, but I need this app to be available to everyone api 19 and higher, Google say no, I need to add multiple apk's I get that, but how do you restrict the target version. So here's an app that target only 4.4, here's one for all v5.x, and finally here's 6+ which goes all the way to v8.1. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing target SDK and minSDK.

Target SDK says which SDK you used to develop, and have you correctly handled things like runtime permissions which only came in with SDK 23.

You might find [this blog post helpful in explaining the differences](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).
For more information see:
[SDK 23 based permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)
[Requesting permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

It sounds like you want a single SDK with minSDK=19 and targetSDK=23,  this is perfectly OK.

Comment: Currently doing this:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:maxSdkVersion="20" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:maxSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>

So I will reads the doc and amend accordingly, thanks x

Comment: Using maxSdk version is nearly always a mistake. You don't need it even if you have multiple APKs. But I suspect you only need one SDK with minSDK 19, and targetSDK 23, and no maxSDK version.

Comment: I shall test later, we are due another build today anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, this seems to be a thing: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Sadly, you have to edit the manifest manually to create the different versions and then archive it for each release, with a new version number. But it works.

[image: screenshot of Google Play showing different uploaded versions in the same release.]

Comment: [You also need read this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html#CreateLibrary)